# Easy to use but versatile hotkey manager for windows?

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a program that allows me to set global hotkeys in windows, but that is

- easy to use if you just want to do something simple, but
- general and customizable for when you want to do something more specific.

I found the program AutoHotkey, but it seems like it has a somewhat steep learning curve. e.g. you have to script stuff even for simple things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free [Clavier+](http://utilfr42.free.fr/util/Clavier.php?sLang=en) setup and configuration is intuitive, and it provides options for shortcuts to programs, files and folders, special çharactérs [oops], etc.

[image: Clavier +]

Hint: To have a program run as Administrator, first make a Windows link to the application, set the link's *Advanced* property to *Run as administrator* [sic] and then create a keyboard shortcut to the link (.lnk) file.